# RSpec with let and subject features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There is the following spec:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Place do
  let(:place) { FactoryGirl.create(:place) }

  subject { place }

  it { expect be_valid }

  describe 'when content is not present' do
    before { place.content = nil }
    it { expect be_valid }
  end
end
```

Also there is validation for presence content in Place model. But this spec doesn't throw any exception, even if the last instruction sets 'content' as nil. What's the trouble? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are just setting an expectation but never calling anything.
Replace your expect be_valid calls with

```
it { expect(subject).to be_valid }
...
it { expect(place).to be_valid }
```

I guess you are coming from the old should syntax. There you could have written it the way you did:

```
it { should be_valid }
```

But the newer expect syntax behaves slightly different

Answer (score 0):

You have `let(:place) { FactoryGirl.create(:place) }`, so when you reference `place` for the first time then it creates an instance (with valid content). You are then changing `content`, but validation is not performed on it.

There are a few ways for doing what you need:

1. Use the factory that you already have, but instead of `create` use `build`
2. Define an invalid factory at `FactoryGirl`:

   ```
   factory :place do
     content 'valid value'
     factory :invalid_place do
       content nil
     end
   end
   ```

3) Or you can use `attributes_for`